# Is there a way to disable plugins during macro recording and execution?

Tags: macro, plugin

Is there a way I can disable specific (or all) plugins when recording a macro and then when playing back the macro?

I've had an issue where a plugin that automatches `(` with `)` that stops a macro that types `(` from playing back correctly. There's a work-around by recording the macro differently, but a way to turn plugins off for macros would be more convenient.

Comment: Oh, in this particular case, `<C-v>(` might do it, don’t know why I didn’t think of that earlier

Comment: For the global case... plugins are, generally speaking (there are exceptions), at least partially loaded into memory when Vim starts up. While you can disable some plugin's functionality by toggling a flag that kind of thing is entirely dependent on the plugin. There's no general mechanism for disabling them. You'll have to run your macro in a new instance of Vim started with flag `--noplugin`.